# Css responsive circle with image inside

Tags: css, responsive-design, geometry

Blue div has fixed height and responsive width, inside there should be a circle image with same height.

This is what I have tried:

https://jsfiddle.net/xnkkrhnt/1/

How do I make perfect centered circle always 100% height of blue div (until blue div width because smaller than height) and image always covering full circle?

```
<div class="player-holder">
    <div class="player-thumb"><img src="http://www.whatcar.com/car-leasing/images/vehicles/medium/100895.jpg"/></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want use only this image? or different images?

Comment: I will switch images with javascript, I hope this doesnt make a difference.

Answer (score 6):

If you want a perfect circle firts your image needs to be square example 300x300 or 500x500, but your image is 360x270, for that reason you have getting a oval.

If you can't make that image a square, you can create a div with dimensions like square, here the example:

HTML

```
<div class="player-holder">
  <div class="player-thumb"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.player-holder{
   height:350px;
   max-width:650px;
   background:blue;
   text-align: center;
}
.player-thumb{
   width: 350px;
   height: 350px;
   display: inline-block;
   border-radius: 50%;
   background-image: url(http://www.whatcar.com/car-leasing/images/vehicles/medium/100895.jpg);
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center;
}
```

Here the example: https://jsfiddle.net/xnkkrhnt/5/

Regards

Comment: Can I make circle responsive when I change blue div height? https://jsfiddle.net/xnkkrhnt/7/

Comment: Yes you can set on the class .player-thumb with and height 100% but your class .player-holder needs to be ever square for example 300x300 or 400x400... etc. because if you do not square, you'll get an oval on your image. https://jsfiddle.net/xnkkrhnt/11/

Answer (score 1):

It's probably better to use background.

Try this:

```css
.player-holder{
 height:350px;
  max-width:650px;
  background:blue;
}
.player-thumb{
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
   border-radius: 100%;
   overflow:hidden;
   background-color: white;
   background-image: url("http://www.whatcar.com/car-leasing/images/vehicles/medium/100895.jpg");
   background-size: contain;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div class="player-holder">
  <div class="player-thumb"></div>
</div>
```

Or on jsfiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xnkkrhnt/9/).

Also,
in order to make a perfect circle, you will need a square size div (350x350 in your case).
Try this jsfiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/xnkkrhnt/10/).

```css
.player-holder {
  height: 350px;
  max-width: 650px;
  min-width: 350px;
  /* assign a min-width */
  background: blue;
}
.player-thumb {
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 350px;
  /* make a fixed width */
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url("http://www.whatcar.com/car-leasing/images/vehicles/medium/100895.jpg");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div class="player-holder">
  <div class="player-thumb"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Updated the answer, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with `background-size` but you have to use images on background.

HTML:

```
<div class="player-holder">
  <div class="player-thumb"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.player-holder{
   height:350px;
   max-width:650px;
   background:blue;
}
.player-thumb{
   height: 100%;
   border-radius: 100%;
   overflow:hidden;
   background: url(http://www.whatcar.com/car-leasing/images/vehicles/medium/100895.jpg);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/xnkkrhnt/3/